# Referring to the data passed to the template using $root

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I have a template:

```
<script id="segment-instructions" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="foreach: Conjunctions">
        <!-- Deep hierarchy -->
            <p data-bind="visible: !$root.hasAnyValidExpression($data)" />             
    </div>
</script>
```

And the following markup where I use it:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="options-tabs">
    ...
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'segment-instructions', data: Instructions }"></div>
</div>
```

This is how I apply the binding:

```
var instructionsModel = new SegmentInstructionsModel();
...

ko.applyBindings({
    GeneralOptions: generalOptionsModel,
    Instructions: instructionsModel
}, $('#options-tabs').get(0));
```

The problem is that `$root` in the template is resolved to the object passed to `ko.applyBindings` (i.e. the object with `GeneralOptions` and `Instructions` properties), not to the object specified in the `template` binding, which is an instance of my `SegmentInstructionsModel` class.

I could solve this in at least two ways, none of which I like:

1. Keep using `$root` in the template, but traversing down to the actual view model rendered by the template

   ```
   <p data-bind="visible: !$root.Instructions.hasAnyValidExpression($data)" />
   ```

   I don't like this since the template should not worry about how the object *above* the actual view model is structured.
2. Use the `$parents` array

   ```
   <p data-bind="visible: !$parents[$parents.length - 2].hasAnyValidExpression($data)" />
   ```

   I don't like this for obvious reasons (for one, it stops working once the actual template's view model is passed to `ko.applyBinding`)

Is there a way to keep using `$root` in a template and not worry about tight coupling of the template with the way its consumer supplies the data to it?

Comment: Is there anything glaringly obvious I'm missing here, or could you just do `<p data-bind="visible: !$parent.hasAnyValidExpression($data)" />`? This is just as robust as using `$root` if $root would equal the data passed into the template. I don't really understand your problem with the `$parents` array, but since you obviously need to go only one level higher, `$parent` is more straightforward. Sidenote: I must say I was under the impression that $root indeed pointed to the data passed into the template. Are you really, really sure it doesn't?

Comment: @Hans My bad, I wrote the example as if using `$parent` would work. It would not in my case, as the hierarchy is pretty deep. The problem with using the `$parents` array is that its correctness depends on how exactly the template consumer provides the model, which is unacceptable. And yes, I am sure `$root` does not point to the data passed to the template.

Comment: This may be a silly suggestion, but what if you'll pass your data to template as follows: `data : { Instructions : Instructions }`. Would this make your new object the actual $root for the template?

Comment: Maybe an alternative would be to upgrade to Knockout 3.2 and use a component? This seems ideal for the modulair approach you are aiming for. http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin It would not as apparently `$root` always points to whatever had been supplied to `ko.applyBindings`. I'm just not sure whether there is some mechanism to override since especially when using templates it looks like a typical problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, using the `$parents` array looks like the way to go, only traversing from the bottom instead from the top (which is not reliable, see above). That is, in my case it would be something like

```
<p data-bind="visible: !$parents[3].hasAnyValidExpression($data)" />
```